# JavaScript Ajax request not working in Firefox and Google Chrome, but it is okay in Safari

Tags: javascript, ajax, arduino

I'm using some JavaScript to send an Ajax request to an Arduino webserver and change the [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) on a webpage.

In Safari this has been working great, but when I try to load it in Firefox and Google Chrome the document elements never update. In the debugger consoles I can see the requests and responses coming back so I'm guessing that there is an issue with parsing the response to an array?

Here is the code:

```
function GetSwitchState()
{
    nocache = "&nocache=" + Math.random() * 1000000;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4)  {
            if (this.status == 200) {
                if (this.responseText != null) {
                    var response = this.responseText;
                    var comma = ",";
                    var inputArray = response.split(comma);
                    var green = inputArray[0];
                    var red = inputArray[1];
                    var fault = inputArray[2];
                    var counter = inputArray[3];
                    document.getElementById('green').innerHTML = green;
                    document.getElementById("red").innerHTML = red;
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = fault;
                    document.getElementById("cars").innerHTML = counter;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", "url" + nocache, true);
    request.send(null);
    setTimeout('GetSwitchState()', 1000);
}
```

The response from the Arduino webserver is four comma-separated values.

Comment: Do you see the correct string in `response`?

Comment: Yes if I put the http request directly into my browser bar I get the string back. This works the three browsers.

Comment: I meant what do you see in the debugger when you look at `this.responseText`

Comment: When I went to look at the debugger it appeared that the ready state never advanced past 2 in firefox, leaving the variables undefined. Maybe that is the actual problem? Its not able to enter the pass the if(ready state == 4) statement?

Comment: I thought you got past that because you guessed the problem was with parsing the response to an array.

Comment: Yeah I thought I was getting past it too...

Answer (score 0):

What I did today was pretty much the same!

When I ran an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to a [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) file and wanted to return an array I needed to specify the return-datatype as "json". In my PHP file I then returned my values like this:

```
return json_encode(array(
    'success' => false,
    'error' => $_POST['password_hashed']
));
```

I was acctually using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to run the request. That looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'script.php',
    data: 'password_hashed=' + hex_sha512(str_password) + '&email=' + str_email, //Clientside password hashing
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(value){
    //Ajax successfully ran
        alert(value.success + '_' + value.error); //=false_[hash]
    },
    error: function(){
    //Ajax error occured -> Display error message in specified element
        alert('error with request');
    }
});
```

I just started with Ajax two days ago, and this may not help a lot, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Noel, I'm not familiar with jQuery at all. Is it possible for me to recreate this javascript into jQuery fairly easily? Or am I looking at starting from scratch?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with javascript since I directly started with JQuery (It's a lot easier and shorter). You would need to link the newest JQuery library from http://www.jquery.com as a *.js file. As said -> I don't fully understand your javascript code. Are you just trying to pass some values to a file via GET parameters? I could provide some code for you if you want ... Oh I forgott, JQuery is a Javascript Library so you will be able to write javascript and JQuery on the same line of code, no changes needed!

Comment: Okay I'll take a look at playing with jQuery a little bit later today. Thanks!

Comment: you can ask if you have questions noel.widmer@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Okay it looks like the issue was actually getting past the

```
{
            if (this.readyState == 4)  {
                if (this.status == 200) {
```

arguments. When I changed it to:

```
{  
     if(response.readState == 4) {
```

I was able to move past that statement in firefox. To get the status to 200 instead of 0 I needed to modify the response header on the arduino side to include:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

To allow Cross Origin Domain Requests in FireFox. Once I made these changes the code works great, I guess I was barking up the wrong tree with my array assumption.
Thanks for the help!